# Prevent Sharing Wifi Settings Between Users on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

I've noticed that if I connect to an access point when logged in as one user, and then switch accounts to another user, that user can also use that wifi connection without needing to re-enter the password / connection information. Is there a way to prevent this, and isolate the settings for a particular network to only be available to one Windows user account?

Comment: If you find nothing withing Windows, maybe you could try something like requiring the password all the time, BUT if you're on the user who has access, then a third party program (say, AutoHotKey? I'm not knowledgeable about those things) will automatically log you in.

Comment: No, I'd rather not do that. Still hoping someone may have a definitive answer to the original question, even if it's just "no, you can't do that".